# Future in the past including SHOULD

Tags: past-tense, future

**How to talk about the future in the past regarding the modal verb SHOULD?**
To give an example, let's say that at the beginning of the month our department received an instruction: "You should change the marketing by the end of the month".
Now, some time after we think back about it. Should we say: *"The instruction stated we should change the strategy?"* or rather: *"The instruction stated we should have changed the strategy"*? As a rule of thumb we use past tenses to talk about future in the past, don't we? Which version is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about an obligation or recommendation made in the past for  future action, ``should'' can be followed by a  base verb.

In your example,  the instruction was given at the beginning of the month to make the change  by the end of the month, so you can  talk about it using the past tense. Both versions you suggested are correct and acceptable, but with slightly different meanings.

- "*The instruction stated we should change the strategy*" means that the instruction was to change the strategy and this is still relevant now.
- "*The instruction stated we should have changed the strategy*" implies that the action should have been done already by the time this statement was made, which may not be the case.

So if changes were made, the first version would be better. The second version may be more accurate if changes have not yet been made.